# Do I have to create a new private an public key if I want to connect by ssh in the opposite way?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a `ssh` configuration to connect to my VPS from my localhost, but I want to send backups from my VPS to my localhost, and I need `ssh` authentication. I'm going through this instructions: [SSH/Community Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#keys-with-specific-commands) and [SSHKeys/Community Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) , but I don't know if new keys must be generated to connect in the opposite way.

Comment: Instead of sending backups from your VPS to localhost, you can also use your existing key to pull them to localhost (e.g. using `scp` or `rsync`). That way, if someone gets access to your VPS, they don't also get access to localhost (and adding a passphrase as suggested by @Oliver Salzburg might be difficult if you want to automate things). Alternatively, you could look into restricting a key to specific commands, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615

Comment: I'll try the first option using `scp`. Could you post an answer with the steps I must follow? I have configured the crontab job with the backups, it only remains for me to do the next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending backups from your VPS to localhost, you can also use your existing key to pull them to localhost (e.g. using `scp` or `rsync`). That way, if someone gets access to your VPS, they don't also get access to localhost (and adding a passphrase as suggested by Oliver Salzburg might be difficult if you want to automate things).

Assuming you have already setup ssh key access from localhost to your VPS, depending on your specific setup it could be as simple as (on localhost):

```
scp -r username@vps:backup-directory local-copy-directory
```

Note that `rsync` might be much more bandwidth efficient if you're repeatedly making backups of slowly changing data.

Comment: All right! I hadn't think before. It's much easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to generate a new pair. You could just copy the key pair from one host to the other and reuse it (remember to put the public key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).

It's probably a good idea to use a new pair though. Otherwise, if someone gets a hold of your private key for one system, he also has the key for the other.

Always remember to protect your private keys with a passphrase.

Comment: I'll try the @eldering option first.